# how to use oneDAL's Naive Bayes classifier in R?

Tags: python, r, intel, naivebayes, xeon-phi

I need to speed up my Naive Bayes classiffication in R. I found an article which describes how to use Intel DAAL's Naive Bayes classifier from R and since I have a Xeon Phi that the library could use I thought that's a good approach: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1151606/Lightning-Fast-R-Machine-Learning-Algorithms but the problem is that DAAL is the old name and version. It now became oneDAL (part of oneAPI). I wasn't able to use the information from the article to get it working with oneDAL and I can't find where I can get DAAL (the older version, to which the article applies).

I would either need instructions for oneDAL to integrate it with R (equivalent to the ones in the article, for DAAL) or a way to obtain DAAL, the old version.

The last resort, I imagine I could use Python (for which there is more info available for oneDAL than R) to do the classification and then transfer the results to R to continue work there.

Comment: Reads like: Please read the manual for my card and write up code for it. You even expect use to go out and search for the API docs.

Comment: @IRTFM granted I could have made my question more clear (and I'll edit it thanks to you) but you got my question all wrong. Why in the world would anybody needing a fast NB classifier write code for it for Xeon Phi when when Intel already did it in the DAAL/oneDAL library? I simply want to use the library's NB's functionality from R and if anybody did it and has some input I'd appreciate the help. The link I pointed to does show how to do it but for the older version (DAAL) which I can't seem to find. I either need similar instructions for oneDAL or a way to get the old library DAAL.

Comment: @IRTFM I didn't end up asking the question by starting with the Xeon Phi (which is getting dust I'm not even sure where) but instead I found the article I referenced that can improve performance for NB and it mentioned working with Xeon Phi processors. Since I have one, assuming I can find it, then... why not?  In the worst case, as I said, I'll do it in Python which has more info on oneDAL and then move the results to R.

Answer (score 0):

Although there was indeed name change from DAAL to oneDAL, but all API's and internals remain the same. So I would expect things to keep working based on what is written in instruction.
You can get 2020.3 version that was last before the renaming - https://anaconda.org/intel/daal/files

There is python api for Naive Bayes https://intelpython.github.io/daal4py/algorithms.html#multinomial-naive-bayes

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay. Meantime I moved away from NB and wrote my own machine learning algorithm so I'm no longer in need to use DAAL's NB library so I won't go into the trouble of getting back to this and testing your answer but I appreciate taking the time to answer my question.  I wish you the best!

Comment: Anyway, I do remember that it didn't work out of the box, some internal names were changed.